# How to remove [None, None] from 2D array

Tags: python, arrays, nonetype

I am wondering how to remove all [None, None] from this kind of array:

```
array([['_603686_SS', '_688598_SS'],
       ['_603686_SS', '_688516_SS'],
       ['_603686_SS', '_600563_SS'],
       ...,
       [None, None],
       [None, None],
       [None, None]], dtype=object)
```

And after removing the [None,None]s, how can I convert the array into a list.
Thank you!

Comment: Do you want a 2D array or a 1D array? What is desired output?

Answer (score 0):

use list comprehension with a conditional to remove rows where all values are null

```
valores = [['_603686_SS', '_688598_SS'],
           ['_603686_SS', '_688516_SS'],
           ['_603686_SS', '_600563_SS'],
           [None, None],
           [None, None],
           [None, None]]
valores = [v for v in valores if v != [None, None]]
valores
```

or use the 'in' conditional if you want to exclude the rows that at least one value is 'None'

```
valores = [['_603686_SS', '_688598_SS'],
           ['_603686_SS', '_688516_SS'],
           ['_603686_SS', '_600563_SS'],
           [None, 'Testando'],
           ['Testando', None],
           [None, None]]
valores = [v for v in valores if not(None in v)]
valores
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [boolean indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) and then convert to a list:

```
a = np.array([['_603686_SS', '_688598_SS'],
       ['_603686_SS', '_688516_SS'],
       ['_603686_SS', '_600563_SS'],
       [None, None],
       [None, None],
       [None, None]], dtype=object)

list(a[a != None])
```

Output:

```
['_603686_SS',
 '_688598_SS',
 '_603686_SS',
 '_688516_SS',
 '_603686_SS',
 '_600563_SS']
```

Note: this will remove all `None`s not all `[None, None]`s.

Comment: Good use of indexing!